# Top level routines of one library are inaccessible when loaded through another library in Dart

Tags: dart, libraries

Say, I load this script in the browser:

```html
<script src='app.dart' type='application/dart'></script>
```

Now, in *app.dart* I have this:

```dart
import 'library1.dart';
unleashTheKraken();
```

Then in *library1.dart* you'll find this:

```dart
library library1;
import 'library2';
```

And finally in *library2.dart* we'll have:

```dart
library library2;
unleashTheKraken() => print('Unleashing the Kraken')
```

And the result is: `Exception: No top-level method 'unleashTheKraken' declared.` How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because imports don't chain automatically. You have to use the `export` statement for that.

```dart
library library1;

import "library2.dart";
export "library2.dart";
```

And to avoid unnecessary code: `import` and `export` are completely independent. If you don't use `unleashTheKraken` in library1 itself, you can omit the import statement and just use export alone.